# How to access private class inside a static nested class

Tags: java, nested

```
class Sample{
       static class Inner{
          private class Private{
              private void print(){
                 System.out.println("accessed");
              }
          }
       }
      public static void main(String[] args){
        #access the print() method from here
}}
```

Here How can I access the private class from the main() method.I can initialize static class object,after that how to initialize the private class?

Comment: Why are you using inner classes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just access it.  Also, you've got a static inner class and then a non-static inner inner. You don't want to have non-static inner classes unless you fully understand java, and clearly, so far, you don't, yet. So, that's off limits for now.

```
class Sample{
       static class Inner {
          private static class Private {
              private void print() {
                 System.out.println("accessed");
              }
          }
       }

      public static void main(String[] args){
          Inner.Private pr = new Inner.Private();
          pr.print();
      }
}
```

or if you really must:

```
class Sample{
       static class Inner {
          private class Private {
              private void print() {
                 System.out.println("accessed");
              }
          }
       }

      public static void main(String[] args){
          Inner i = new Inner();
          Inner.Private pr = i.new Private();
          pr.print();
      }
}
```

`i.new`??

Yeah. That's the syntax. I told you you don't want this for a reason.

Comment: Yes,The 2nd block code works for me.Initially Got little confusion in creating object reference for static class.
Now its very clear to me.Thanks buddy.